# get the valuesfrom jsp to excel in report form

Tags: jsp

Im trying to download jsp data(here the data is got from oracle database)  to an excel sheet

This is  what im trying to do

```
<b>DOWNLOAD : </b><a href="Report.jsp?exportToExcel=YES">A_REPORT</a>
<%    
    String exportToExcel = request.getParameter("exportToExcel");
    if (exportToExcel != null && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
    {  
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""A_REPORT.xls"); 
    } 
 %>
```

im getting blank data along with a button and two text boxes  which is displayed in jsp, but the data from table is not showing up

Comment: How is CSS related to Excel file?

Comment: can you show us some more code, may be the header part?

Comment: @Alex : i have included  css in my jsp and when click on the link it gives me an error as missing stylesheet.css and opens excel  with blank data and one button and tow textbox which is there in jsp

Comment: @abu : i have given the full code, the rest part of the code is just getting the data from database

Comment: please post a code snippet please